# SVM for character and digit recognition

Tags: image-processing, svm, libsvm, feature-detection, feature-extraction

just for scientific research and to compare with some other methods I am doing character and digit recognition on a single image.

this is original image.

[image]

after some processing my final image become like this.

[image]

I've manually cropped all characters in paint.

[image]  ,  [image]   , [image]

now I wanna do **SVM** on this **single** image to detect those characters.

I've binary format of images too such as

0

```
0000000000000000000000
0000000000001000000000
0000000111111110000000
0000011111111111100000
0001111111111111110000
0011111111111111111000
0011111111111111111100
0011110000000011111111
0011110000000001111111
0111100000000000011111
0111100000000000011111
0111000000000000011111
1111000000000000011111
1111000000000000001111
1111000000000000001111
1111000000000000001111
1111000000000000001111
1111000000000000011111
1111000000000000011111
1111000000000000011111
1111000000000000011111
1111000000000000011110
1111000000000000011110
0111100000000000111110
0111100000000000111100
0111110000000011111100
0111111111001111111100
0011111111111111111000
0011111111111111111000
0011111111111111110000
0000111111111111000000
0000000111111100000000
0000000000010000000000
0000000000000000000000
```

8

```
0000000000000000000000
0000000000100000000000
0000011001111000000000
0000111111111111000000
0001111111111111111000
0011111110000011111110
0011111100000000111111
0111111000000000011111
0111100000000000001111
0111100000000000001111
0111100000000000000111
0111100000000000000111
0111100000000000000111
0111110000000000011110
0011111111111111111110
0011111111111111111110
0011111111111111111100
0011111111111111111100
0011111111111111111100
0011111111110011111100
0011111100000011111100
0011111000000000111100
0011111000000000111100
0011111000000000111110
0011111000000000111110
0011111100000000111110
0001111100000001111100
0001111111111111111000
0000111111111111110000
0000111111111111100000
0000011111111111000000
0000000011111110000000
0000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000
```

H

```
001000000000000000001100
011000000000000000001110
011100000000000000011110
011100000000000000011110
011110000000000000011110
011110000000000000011110
111110000000000000011110
111110000000000000011110
011110000000000000011110
011110000000000000011110
011111111111001111111110
011111111111111111111110
011111111111111111111110
011111111111111111111110
011111111111111111111110
011111111111111111111110
011111111100000001111110
001111000000000000111110
001111000000000000011110
001111000000000000011110
001110000000000000011100
001110000000000000011100
001110000000000000011100
000110000000000000011100
000110000000000000011100
000110000000000000001100
000110000000000000000000
```

my question is since I'll use this method in a **specific image** which means there wont be any rotation or perspective problems.
can I just train those characters with **libsvm** and match? or do I have to do some kind of feature extraction method such as **SIFT**, **SURF**, **FAST** etc before doing a matching on libsvm?

P.S: a real good documentation about libsvm would also be appreciated.

Comment: Work on the MNIST database with digit recognition started out with taking each digit patch, turning them into single column vectors, and using these as feature vectors to be input into a neural network for training.  However, I have also seen this applied to SVM as well, but you're going to need a lot more digits to your training framework if you want this to be robust against scale, rotation, etc.  Try getting data from MNIST and train a classifier with these digits, then use what you detected in your images as input into the classifier for classification: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/.

Comment: @rayryeng hey since I am going to SVM on this special image cant I just crop those characters and train them ?

Comment: Sure you can but you're going to need more than one of each to classify incoming characters. You can't just use one image per digit or letter. It won't be accurate enough.

Comment: @rayryeng can you suggest me a good tutorial about classifying in libsvm ? the documentation itself was not good enough.

Comment: Sure! I'm on my way to work so I'll change my comments to an answer, as well as show you how to use it when I get in. Which language are you using btw?

Comment: @rayryeng currently I am doing image processing part in matlab and libsvm part on the console however after I'll do all in OpenCV and C++

Comment: OK. I'll write you an answer using the MATLAB wrappers. Seems that MATLAB is the best way to tie it all together. Stay tuned!

Comment: @rayryeng will you write the answer today ? I am stucked so badly hopefully your answer will help me :)

Comment: Sorry boss. Work got busy. I will very soon. On vacation now.

Comment: @rayryeng hello I just wanted to say I'm still waiting thank you!